# Taylor Series for $(1-x)^p$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Can anybody help me with the Taylor series for $(1-x)^p$? I have no idea how to do it. I know that:

$(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+...$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you mean for $p$ to be negative (or even noninteger), you *really* should state that in the problem.

Comment: @Hurkyl: why ? This Taylor development works for all $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was meant to be a reply but I am not sure how to properly render latex in comments so I apologise for that.
$$(1-x)^{-3}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \binom{-3}{n}(-x)^n=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \binom{n+2}{n}x^n=1+3x+6x^2+10x^3+15x^4+...$$
using $$\binom{-n}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k$$

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I thought they would have alternating signs to be honest. I tried solving this myself and couldn't get the answer you got. I got: (2 OVER 0)x^0 + (3 OVER 1)x^1 + (4 OVER 2)x^2+... which I simplified to: 2+6x+12x^2

Comment: Yup I'm pretty sure this is correct. You should probably go check out the newton's generalised binomial theorem section on this page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem

Comment: Okay thank you for your help, I think I finally understand it... so for (1-x)^-4, the answer is 1+4x+10x^2+... Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You are the king. You are the maths king.

Comment: You are welcome for the help. But I'm merely a student who happens to have some superficial knowledge in Math. The compliment of "math king" is too far of a stretch.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=(1-x)^p$. We see that
$$f'(0)=-p$$
$$f''(0)=p(p-1)$$
and so on so $f^{(n)}(0)=(-1)^np(p-1)...(p-n+1)$. Hence
$$(1-x)^p=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-1)^n\frac{p(p-1)...(p-n+1)}{n!}x^n=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\binom{p}{n}(-1)^nx^n$$

Comment: Thank you so far, could you help me with an example for further understanding? For example, if p=-3, then the T.S. would be:

1+(-3 OVER 1)(-1)^1(x)^1+(-3 OVER 2)(-1)^2(x)^2+...

This would equal: 1-6x+3x^2+... Is this correct?

Comment: How about when p = 1/2?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the [binomial expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Since the Taylor series is unique, it is also the Taylor expansion.

The power can also be negative or fractional. In that case you need the generalised binomial theorem, that generalizes the binomium for negative and non-integer values. For instance $\binom{-3}{2} = \frac{-3 \cdot -2}{1 \cdot 2} = 3$.

Comment: Doesn't the power have to be positive with binomial expansion though?

Comment: Edited the answer.